# What is the best way to count and display the number of posts?

Tags: count, server-load, cache

I have a section in my site where I display the 10 most popular posts. Now, I want to display a number, from 1 to 10, besides each post. Like this:

Top 10 posts

1. post a
2. post b
3. post c

and so on...

I implemented a counter inside the while loop. I initialized the counter at 0 `$counter = 0;` and then incremented it by one `<?php echo ++$counter; ?>`

My concern is, due to my site receiving thousands of visits a day, I want to know if this method will consume my site's resources considerably. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe to implement some sort of caching?

What advice can you give me?

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to use an ordered list.

```
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
    echo '<ol style="list-style:decimal">';
    while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
      echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
    endwhile;
    echo '</ol>';
endif;
```

Comment: +1 from me. I always write php and forgot that html exists :)

Comment: I tried your solution, however, the numbers are not displaying.

Comment: @Gixty is a css problem, I think.

Comment: @Gixty added `style="list-style:decimal"` to force number showing

Comment: @Horttcore: Thank you!! yes it is, i found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643913/how-can-i-show-numbers-on-an-inline-ordered-list

Comment: @G.M. why was your answer erased?? I needed to check something out.